# Как реализовать вывод данных из БД?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть input:

```
<form method="get" action="/search">
            <div class="search-line">
                <input type="text" id="search-line-id" name="search" placeholder="Поиск..." class="search-line-class" title="Поиск по сайту" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
</form>
```

Всё написанное в нём кидается в `/search` на бэк.

бэк siteController:

```
public function actionSearch() 
    {
        $search = Yii::$app->request->get('search');

        $search1 = ucfirst(str_replace(" ", "", $search));

        $query = Documentation::find()
        ->where([
            'like', 
            'creature_name', $search1
        ]);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        return $this->render('search', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
        ]);
    }
```

Получаю методом get инфу из `input'a` с `name="search"` и по ней ищу что-то похожее(как я понимаю) в колонке `creature_name` в БД. Далее, найдя совпадения, возвращаю всё в dataProvider'е. И отрисовываю его на странице данным способом:

```
<?=ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}",
])?>
```

Он находит нужное поле, где `input` совпадает с `creature_name` в базе, но отрисовывает только id'шник(первая ячейка всей строки), всю остальную инфу он не показывает.

Не до конца понимаю, как вытащить из dataProvider всю остальную инфу. Хотя бы посмотреть, что содержится в нём.

Comment: первое - можно воспользоваться отладкой и банально в отладчике посмотреть на содержимое объекта dataProvider. Второе - ещё банальнее - посмотреть в документацию yii2 по объекту dataProvider  и посмотреть какие свойства и методы он предлагает.

Comment: " как вытащить из dataProvider всю остальную инфу. " --- какую именно?  можно посмотреть документацию по ListView чтобы увидеть как именно информацию можно отображать  (или примеры в сети https://vivasart.com/lab/yii2-kak-sozdat-predstavlenie-listview-ishodniki  .....  https://кодер.укр/записи/yii-2-вывод-списка-записей-с-помощью-виджета-listview-подробный-пример  ....  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/output-data-widgets)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, видимо, я не особо соображаю, как правильно делать отладку переменной, потому что у меня пишется чисто: что ищется, где ищется и по какому параметру)
Насчёт документации огромное спасибо. Всё получилось как нужно было)!